Yaml to deploy SQL script using Azure DevOps
In our git repo we have a folder called ExternalSQLScripts with sub-folders for Tables, Views, Functions, StoredProcedures etc. Loop through each sub-folder and execute all the .sql files on the external SQL Server. We only have access to just deploy the SQL Server database object scripts we cannot do a .dacpac database deploy.
While I try to run my pipeline I run into 2 issues:
1) (Get-Module was unexpected at this time. Cmd.exe exited with code '255'.
2) PublishBuildArtifacts task throws error and I had to exclude it from the pipeline.

In general what would be the best approach to deploy SQL Server database scripts.
YAML:
variables:
  sqlServerConnection: $(System.ConnectionStrings.DatabaseConnectionString)
  sqlScriptPath: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/ExternalSQLScripts

steps:
- script: |
    # Install SqlServer module
    if (-!Test-Path (Get-Module -ListAvailable SqlServer)) {
      Install-Module SqlServer -Scope CurrentUser -Force
    }

    Get-ChildItem -Path $sqlScriptPath -Filter "*.sql" -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    $scriptPath = $_.FullName
    $scriptName = $_.BaseName

    try {
        Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $sqlServerConnection -Database [System.DefaultWorkingDirectory] -InputFile $scriptPath
        Write-Host "Successfully executed script: $scriptName"
    } catch {
        Write-Error "Error executing script: $scriptName - $($_.Exception.Message)"
    }
}
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    inputs:
      pathToPublish: $(sqlScriptPath)
      artifactName: sql-scripts


Hi @paone, Have you got a chance to check the answer by Shamrai below to use powershell task instead of script task? Does it work to resolve the error in this post? Thx.

This step runs cmd.exe instead of PowerShell:
steps:
- script:

Check this link: steps.script definition

The script step runs a script using cmd.exe on Windows and Bash on
other platforms.

Change it to PowerShell@2.
